# git - Could not resolve proxy:

Tags: git, proxy

In work I have a proxy, at home I don't have a proxy

In work I set the proxy like:

```
    git config - -global  http.proxy  http://proxy.theaddress.co.uk:8080
    git config - -global  https.proxy  https://proxy.theaddress.co.uk:8080
```

At home I remove the proxy like

```
    git config --global --unset http.proxy
    git config --global --unset https.proxy
```

I'm trying to push something to my git repo with

```
    git push -u origin master
```

And I get

```
    Could not resolve proxy: proxy.theaddress.co.uk
```

The .gitconfig file looks like this.

```
    [user]
        name = first last
        email = first.last@sitname.co.uk
    [http]
    [https]
    [push]
        default = current
    [http]
    [core]
        excludesfile = /Users/first.last/.gitignore_global
    [difftool "sourcetree"]
        cmd = opendiff \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
        path = 
    [mergetool "sourcetree"]
        cmd = /Applications/SourceTree.app/Contents/Resources/opendiff-w.sh \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" -ancestor \"$BASE\" -merge \"$MERGED\"
        trustExitCode = true
    [http]
    [https]
    [http]
    [https]
    [http]
    [https]
    [http]
    [https]
    [http]
    [https]
    [filter "media"]
        clean = git media clean %f
        smudge = git media smudge %f
        required = true
    [http]
    [https]
    [https]
    [http]
    [http]
    [https]
    [http]
```

How do I remove the proxy ?

Comment: Do you have it define as environment variable HTTP_PROXY? or in the config local to the repo (.git/config)?

Comment: I don't see a proxy entry. have you tried git config --global --unset http.proxy? there should be a [http]
    proxy = entry but its not there

Comment: VonC - I don't think I have it defined as an environmental variable, how/where would I check. unixmiah - Yes I've tried git config --global --unset http.proxy, it's in my question. I know there is no proxy entry, which is why I'm confused.

Answer (score 28):

Check the environment variables with :

```
$echo $http_proxy
$echo $https_proxy
$echo $HTTPS_PROXY
$echo $HTTP_PROXY
```

if any of these environment variables are set then unset them by just using `http_proxy=` then `enter` will unset those

```
$export http_proxy=
```

Comment: Is it http.proxy on a mac os?

Comment: Kudos @harip, It worked. You have to patient enough to check all the four versions! Don't give up after finding two or three echo's returning empty!

Answer (score 19):

- Delete all of the following variables if they are set while working on the network having no proxy (Example at the home)

  ```
   //Computer=>System properties=>Advanced=>Environment Variables
   http_proxy,https_proxy,HTTPS_PROXY,HTTP_PROXY
  ```
- Unset git proxy

  ```
   git config --global --unset http.proxy
   git config --global --unset https.proxy
  ```

Both steps together worked for me in Windows.

Comment: Unset git proxy alone worked for me

Answer (score 4):

Solution to this problem is to remove the git proxies.

- Open your terminal through the administrator.
- Then hit command `git config --global -l`
- Then unset all HTTP and https proxies by below command
- `git config --global --unset-all http.proxy` & `git config --global --unset-all https.proxy`
- Now you can check it is removed from the list or not with the same command `git config --global -l`

Answer (score 2):

For Windows/Linux User's Using Bash

```
export http_proxy=""
export https_proxy=""
```

For Windows CMD Users

```
set http_proxy=""
set https_proxy=""
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to other answers (especially the one by @harip) but if you're on a Mac or such, check the .bash_profile file in the user's home directory (e.g. `cat ~/.bash_profile`).
Mine had these set during another program's install:

```
export HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.somewhere.com:80

export HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxy.somewhere.com:80
```

Move that file to the side (e.g. `mv ~/.bash_profile ~/.bash_profile-hide`).
Then start a new Terminal window (which will reload environment variables). If you don't start a new Terminal window, any existing ones will still have the variables set and need to be cleared manually.